# jQuery sticky menu mobile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a sticky menu that follows as soon as the menu position is at top of the browser window. My script works well on both desktop and mobile, however when i visit the website through my phone, it doesn't fire the function **while im scrolling**, only when i release my finger from the screen after scrolling.

How can i make the script fire as im scrolling? My jQuery looks like this:

```
function menuTop(){
    var $header   = $('header'), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $header.offset();

    $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $header.addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $header.removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
}
```

Can i e.g. use $(window).on('touchstart') somewhere in the code to fire menuTop(); as soon as i scrolled?

Comment: Are you using an iPhone with Safari?